# Cancel MVC Ajax.Actionlink based on a condition

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a list of "stuff" in a table, and I have a Details link in each row that will load the details of the item in a hidden row under each visible row, clicking the link again will hide the details of the item. The showing/hiding is done with simple jQuery `fadeToggle()`

Currently the details link is an `Ajax.Actionlink()` that calls the designated action. 
Everything is working fine, except when I want to hide the details, it calls the action again, which calls the logic, which calls the database.
Obviously this is a waste of resources, so I'd like a way to cancel the ajax request when a condition is met; the condition being wether the "details" container is visible.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Details", "DetailsPartial",
                 new AjaxOptions { 
                       OnBegin = "function(){
                            checkLoaded('" + string.Format("DetailContainer{0}", item.Id) + "');
                       }", 
                 HttpMethod = "GET", 
                 UpdateTargetId = string.Format("Detail{0}", item.Id),
                 OnSuccess = "function(){
                                showElement('" + string.Format("DetailContainer{0}", item.Id) + "');
                             }",
                 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace 
                 })
```

I suspect I should be doing the work with OnBegin, but I've yet to find the magic command that cancels the ajax call.
With the `checkLoaded()` function I'm checking `.css('display') == 'none'` for the passed element ID, and so I'd need some cancellation in there.

I've searched for a solution for a while, but couldn't find one, perhaps because I don't know how to ask it smart. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to cancel the action, all you need to do is return false in the OnBegin method.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Details", "DetailsPartial",
                 new AjaxOptions { 
                       OnBegin = "function(){
                            return !checkLoaded('" + string.Format("DetailContainer{0}", item.Id) + "');
                       }", 
                 HttpMethod = "GET", 
                 UpdateTargetId = string.Format("Detail{0}", item.Id),
                 OnSuccess = "function(){
                                showElement('" + string.Format("DetailContainer{0}", item.Id) + "');
                             }",
                 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace 
                 })
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work.  I'm calling a confirm dialog box and returning the result.  Even though the user chooses Cancel and false is returned the actions still goes through :(

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the same issue: AJAX request executed even if anonymous function from previous answer returned false. This happens because the contents of OnBegin is wrapping into anonymous function, and if this function returns false, AJAX request cancels. This solved my issue:

```
...
OnBegin = "return function(){  
   return !checkLoaded('" + string.Format("DetailContainer{0}", item.Id) + "'); 
}", 
...
```